# Calling a web service from javascript and .net 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

> Thanks all for the help, rod.

Hi All,

Is it possible to call a web service (on my localhost) from jquery in a plain html page inside an asp.net 2.0 webform application using visual studio 2005?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){                
            $('#targetDiv').load('http://localhost/testservice/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld',null,function(){alert('test')});
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting a 500 error? Not sure if it's even possible to do this way?

thanks,
rod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ASP.Net doesn't enable web methods for `GET` requests (which is what a data-less [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does).  [Scott Guthrie has a nice blog post on how to enable GET on Web Methods](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx).

However, keep in mind that they're disabled for a reason (security mainly), you may want to just use a [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead, like this:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){                
  $.post('http://localhost/testservice/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld',
    function(data) { $('#targetDiv').html(data); }
  );
});
```

Or make [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) trigger POST with a dummy data object, like this:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){                
  $('#targetDiv')
    .load('http://localhost/testservice/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld', {});
});
```

The `{}` is the key, [passing an object makes `.load()` do a `POST` instead of a `GET`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L42).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this line is correct?
http://localhost/testservice/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld
Have you tried calling the webservice directly through the browser?

Comment: If I goto this link without the '/HelloWorld' I can see the service in my browser...but then how do i call my method called 'HelloWorld()'

Answer (score 1):

Enable web method in the web service so that it can be called with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery + Ajax Instead:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means your web service threw an exception. Look in the event log to find out what the problem is, or debug the web service to find out.